# Mongodb empty when reach to 4gb

Tags: linux, mongodb

My english is not good, so please does not get angry while you reading this :)

I'm facing with the Mongodb on my Linux server. I just started to use Mongodb so i have not much skill to work with.

Mongodb on my server is automation empty when it reach to 4gb and i don't know why! I have do some searches but they not works.
Here is my initial mongodb command

```
sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

The linux server is 64bit. The hardisk is 40GB.
Mongodb v3.0.14

Please help me!
Thanks all!

Comment: Somebody help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide more details on how you have realized that the server is "empty" when you reach 4GB? What does ``show dbs`` show before/after 4GB? What query(s) are you running to make this determination?

Comment: @helmy Thanks for your replied.
when i ran show dbs it showing only one db is: "DB_DELETED"
My 2 database one is PROD and another one is DEV was gone!

Comment: @helmy Also all files from dbpath was gone!